# Tried to send ethereum to contract address, get error in etherscan (gethdebugtrace)

Tags: cpp-ethereum

I sent ethereum to a contract address I made and I always get this error: 
An error occurred during contract execution: exception

What is going wrong here? I used the exact same code provided on https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale#the-code and I deployed it from my mist desktop wallet.

[image: error messages]

Comment: The fallback function of the crowdsale contract modifies the storage multiple times, so it burns a lot of gas. Would be useful to know when you send your transaction how much gas you assign to your ether transfer? One of my guesses is that you simply run out of gas...

Comment: I used 200.000 gas for this transaction. @István András Seres

Comment: So it seems that the fallback function fails for some reason. Let's find out why! Did you deploy the token contract the fallback function is using? Did you give the correct address of this token contract at the constructor of Crowdsale contract? Make sure that the boolean variable crowdsaleClosed is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you a recap, I summarize here as an answer the list of checks you should perform on the fallback function of the deployed crowdsale contract.

This is the fallback function which fails when you send ether to the crowdsel contract:

```
/**
     * Fallback function
     *
     * The function without name is the default function that is called whenever anyone sends funds to a contract
     */
    function () payable {
        require(!crowdsaleClosed);
        uint amount = msg.value;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;
        amountRaised += amount;
        tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount / price);
        FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
    }
```

1. Might be that the tranasction you sent runs out of gas, since the fallback function modifies the storage multiple times, meaning it burns a vast amount of gas.
2. Make sure that the variable `crowdsaleClosed` is still set to `false`.
3. Maybe you forgot to deploy the `tokenReward` token contract before actually deploying the crowdsale contract itself. Its address should have been passed as the last argument of the crowdsale contract constructor function.

Hope you find the bug!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! One question: How do i set the variable crowdsaleclosed to false?

Comment: It is set to false by default and most likely it is still false unless you called the checkGoalReached() function.

Comment: I didnt change anything in the code. Its a simple copy paste into my mist wallet deployer. Why is it giving me this error if i used the exact code provided on the ethereum website?

Comment: You need to create a fixed supply token as mentioned in the link you provided in the question. Did you deploy the token contract before deploying the crowdsale contract??? Did you give the correct address of the deployed token contract in the constructor function of the Crowdsale contract?

Comment: Yep, I did all of that.

Comment: Then, there has nothing left but the tokenreward.transfer() function call. It should fail for some reason...Did you implement a token function in your token contract? How does it look like? What is the value of the minBalanceForAccounts variable? or really my last suggestion is that try to send your transaction with some ridiculously high transaction fee.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. I will deploy the token and the crowdsale contract again from the new ethereum wallet. I will keep you updated if it works or not.

Comment: @Gabriel One quick tip: Make sure you set an 'OnlyOwner' method which changes the status of crowdsaleclosed.